# Need help understanding Gradle Build error

Tags: android, gradle

This is the first time I've run across an error like this, and it indicates to me that I understand significantly less about Android Studio / Gradle than I thought.

When I run a gradle sync, I receive the following error:

```
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/65cf0a0160015e9f883c383ac0bd600d/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml
Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
```

There are a few other errors thrown, but they're more or less the same.

**Part 1)** Pulling apart the URL with `.gradle/caches/...` part of the URL, I can see that I'm trying to build from a version 27 resource (`...appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar...`), but within that build there is a `values-v26.xml` file. That's the first part that is confusing me. Shouldn't they both say the same thing?

Secondly, in my `app/build.grade`, I have specified that I want to use API version 26:

```
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.adrichmobile"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 26
    ....

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

**Part 2)** Why would I be trying to pull from version 27 in the cache? (After clearing the cache, I get the same thing)

Comment: I recommend doing `File - Invalidate Caches/Restart` then `Clean Build`.

Comment: What is your buildToolsVersion ?

Comment: Run `gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt` to examine why v27.1.1 might being pulled in.

Comment: First, many things have version numbers and they have nothing to do with each other. The fact that you are building for API 26 does not mean you cannot use a library with version 27. Second, it seems you are mixing different versions of the support libraries. Check what is pulling in the appcompat-v7-27.1.1 although you have requested appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya where might I find that? I'm not specifying in build.gradle since I thought that was deprecated.

Comment: @JamesPoag I found that react-native is requiring it. I recently updated to the latest version. So, in theory, if I just require API 27 I should still be able to use resources from previous versions, right? I'm wondering why this would appear then: /Users/robertkotcher/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/65cf0a0160015e9f883c383ac0bd600d/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml

Comment: Which build tools version are you using?

Comment: @JamesPoag While I am not specifying it since it's depricated now (I think?), I get the following warning from one of my deps: `The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.`. Does this mean I'm using 27.0.3?

Comment: Open up your SDK Tools and see what you have installed.  Also, which version of Android Studio do you have (or are you just using gradle)?

Comment: @JamesPoag so this is actually I'm not sure about this. When I open SDK tools I see that API levels 23 - 28 have status "partially installed", with the exception of 27 saying "update available". What is the relation to build tools? Is the build tool version equivalent to the API level?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my problem was a common one (with a recent update of react-native), but I was originally searching for things that didn't lead me to this conclusion.

In the end, I had to force my subprojects to build with the tools and SDK, as they hadn't been updated for this release. Looks like this is affecting many react-native projects.

More details can be found here: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/882#issuecomment-405255785

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue because cached files.

I recommend `Clean project` and clear Android Studio cache by menu `File``”Invalidate Caches and Restart…”`

And reboot computer so make Gradle sync again

Comment: hope this article can help you something https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-studio-is-borked-my-checklist-for-fixing-build-issues-e41a9dd8cba8